# Crear listas de una lista general

Tags: lista, algoritmos, arraylist, swift4

tengo una lista la cual ordené por elementos que quisiera obtener. Se trata de nombre de empresas, la idea que quiero es que cuando los objetos de la lista general sean iguales se agrupen en una lista y así sucesivamente. En este ejemplo tengo 1 lista general y resultarían 3 listas al final

```
var companiesf = [
    Directory(directoryId: 1, fullname: "Jose Luis", company: "A"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 2, fullname: "Fernando", company: "A"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 3, fullname: "Maria", company: "B"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 4, fullname: "Rodrigo", company: "B"),
    Directory(directoryId: 5, fullname: "Miguel", company: "C")
]
```

de modo que obtendría 3 listas

```
 var litaA = [
    Directory(directoryId: 1, fullname: "Jose Luis", company: "A"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 2, fullname: "Fernando", company: "A")
]


var listaB = [
    Directory(directoryId: 3, fullname: "Maria", company: "B"), 
    Directory(directoryId: 4, fullname: "Rodrigo", company: "B")
]


var listaC = [
    Directory(directoryId: 5, fullname: "Miguel", company: "C")
]
```

¿Cómo podría lograr eso?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes plantearte 2 alternativas. Tendrías que evaluar cuantos elementos tendrías y la forma de trabajar con los resultados para que fuese lo mas eficiente posible.

Una primera forma seria tenerlo todo como lo tienes ahora y cuando quieras la empresa x hacer un filter sobre la empresa y obtienes un array de esa empresa

```
let companies = companiesf.filter({ $0.company == "A" })
```

Tendrías que estar haciendo filtros cada vez que quieras trabajar con una empresa. Añadir una nueva empresa seria muy fácil, solo añadiendo un elemento mas al array y eliminarlo también seria muy fácil..

Otra opción seria tener un diccionario, donde la clave sea la empresa y el valor sea un array con todos los datos de esa empresa. El acceso seria muy rápido, pero seria mas tedioso el añadir o eliminar un elemento, pero hechos unos métodos para añadir, eliminar o lo que necesites se soluciona rápido.

```
var empresasDict: [String: [Directory] = [:]
```

Para añadir, tendrías que obtener primero lo que ya tienes , añadir el elemento y volver a asignar el resultado, y similar para eliminar.

```
let emp = Directory(company: "com1", name: "pepe", id: 3)
var arrAux = empresasDict["com1"] ?? []
arrAux.append(emp)
empresasDict["com1"] = arrAux
```